# Tensorflow no detecta la GPU en Ubuntu

Tags: python, tensorflow, cuda, gpu

estoy intentando instalar Tensorflow para usar la GPU, pero cuando hago:

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

Recibo como salida:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es decir, un array vacio, y no detecta la GPU.

Os dejo las versiones que tengo instaladas:

- SO: Ubuntu 20.04
- Tensorflow: 2.7
- CUDA: 11.2
- cuDNN: 8.1
- Python: 3.8.10

Por lo que he visto en la web oficial de tensorflow, cumplo los requisitos:

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu

Como añadido, cuando intenta ejecutar un script donde hago uso de la GPU, recibo como salida lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El script que comento arriba es el siguiente (https://deepspeech.readthedocs.io/en/r0.9/):

```
deepspeech --model deepspeech-0.9.3-models.pbmm --scorer deepspeech-0.9.3-models.scorer --audio audio/2830-3980-0043.wav
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente esto sucede por que tensorflow esta ejecutándose con una versión no compatible de CUDA, por lo que veo en el error tensorflow esta buscando la version 10.1 de cuda, pero tu variable de entorno LD_LIBRARY_PATH esta buscando en la versión 11.2 que tienes instalada.

Una posible solución rápida seria que instales libcudart10.1 así:

```
sudo apt-get install libcudart10.1
```

También si pudieras pegar el resultado del comando 'pip list' para ver que efectivamente tengas instalado tensorflow 2.7 ya que se me hace raro que pida la versión 10.1.